# Program to list all windows files in order by size

Tags: shell

Does anyone know of a program or script which lists all the files in your hard drive in descending order by size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a script, but I have used [TreeSize Free](http://download.cnet.com/TreeSize-Free/3000-2248_4-81064.html?tag=mncol).

Comment: All good answers, but I tried this first and it worked great.

Answer (score 2):

WinDirStat is what I use, but it's Windows-only:

http://windirstat.info/images/windirstat.jpg

http://windirstat.info/

It's based on Kdirstat, for X11:

http://kdirstat.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

You can run `dir /O-S` and recurse. The following command does that:

```
for /R  %I in (.) DO dir /O-S
```

This walks the tree starting at current directory. Place your choice of directory after the `/R`.

Answer (score 0):

[JDiskReport](http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/jdiskreport/) does something along these lines.

Answer (score 0):

My "unselfish" recommendation: [RidNacs](http://www.splashsoft.de/Freeware/ridnacs.html)